# Changing Position of UISearchController - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, position, uisearchcontroller

How can I change the position of UISearchController ?
So far, I placed it under the navigationcontroller :

> self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

But I want to achive something like this:

http://postimg.org/image/kwv6xippl/

So under navigation there is UISegmentedControl item, and next is my searchBar...

This is possible to implement? If so , please help :)
Thanks ;)

Comment: Add a static cell to the UITableViewController and drop the search-bar on it. Don't be scare to play around with the storyboard :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a Table View Controller in your storyboard, you can create a View Controller and a Segmented Control, Search Bar and Table View as subviews to the View of the View Controller in that order.

like so...

[image]

Comment: Yes, I've done exactly the same as you. But we can't just drag to storyboard UISearchController (it's new in iOS 8) , so we need to set it's position programmatically, but I don't know how to do it...

Comment: @EvIld95 use the method `addSubview(_ view: UIView)` and pass in the the `searchBar` property of `UISearchController`

Comment: Does your UISearchController have constraints?

Comment: Add some NSLayoutConstraints to the UISearchController to manipulate the position programmatically.